# Creating group dummy variable

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a large data frame that looks something like this

```
   A  B   Q3    Q40   Q41   C
1  *  *   1     NA    NA   *
2  *  *   NA    NA    1    *
3  *  *   NA    1     NA   * 
4  *  *   NA    NA    1    *
5  *  *   1     NA    NA   *
```

I want to create a dummy variable to indicate group designated by Q3,Q40, and Q41. At the end I want the output to look like

```
   A  B   Q3    Q40   Q41   C   Group
1  *  *   1     NA    NA   *   Group1
2  *  *   NA    NA    1    *   Group3
3  *  *   NA    1     NA   *   Group2
4  *  *   NA    NA    1    *   Group3
5  *  *   1     NA    NA   *   Group1
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create this dummy variable "Group." Do I write it as individual functions, as below, or is there an easier way?

```
dummy<- function (df$V1){
if (df$V1==1)
   return ("Group1")
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use `apply` and check rowwise which of V1 to V3 is equal to 1:

```
variables <- c("Q3", "Q40", "Q41")
# Works only for exactly one '1' per row:
# my_df$Group <- apply(my_df[variables], 1, function(x) which(x == 1))
# Works for multiple '1' per row or rows without '1': 
my_df$Group <- apply(my_df[, variables], 1, function(x) paste(which(x %in% 1), collapse = "_"))
my_df$Group <- paste0("Group", my_df$Group)
my_df
#   A B Q3 Q40 Q41 C    Group
# 1 * *  1  NA  NA *   Group1
# 2 * * NA  NA   1 *   Group3
# 3 * * NA   1  NA *   Group2
# 4 * * NA  NA   1 *   Group3
# 5 * *  1  NA   1 * Group1_3
```

**Data**

```
my_df <- read.table(text ="      A  B   Q3    Q40   Q41   C   Group
1  *  *   1     NA    NA   *   Group1
2  *  *   NA    NA    1    *   Group3
3  *  *   NA    1     NA   *   Group2
4  *  *   NA    NA    1    *   Group3
5  *  *   1     NA    1   *   Group1", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you so much! The output when i check my_df$Group looks something like this ```"Groupc(V1 = 1)"  "Groupc(V5 = 5)" "Groupc(V2 = 2)" "Groupc(V2 = 2)```. How can i change the labels so that it's just "Group 1," "Group 2" etc?

Comment: Hmm that looks like the result returned by apply is not a single number but something like `Q3 = 1`. Are you sure you used `==`? Maybe you can adapt your example to match your original dataframe better.

Comment: just updated the example to match what my actual column labels are in the dataset

Comment: I think this might be due to the fact that you have rows with more than one column equal to 1? Although I'm confused by your numbers 5 and 2... This is not reproducible for me but I edited my answer to account for the fact that more columns might be equal to 1.

Comment: I don't have rows where more than one column is one. For each observation 1:5, Q3, or Q40, or Q41 are 1, mutually exclusive. When I run ```df$Group <- apply(df[, 29:31], 1, function(x) which(x == 1))
df$Group <- paste0("Group ", df$Group)``` (where 29:31 is the position of columns Q3,Q40,Q41) and then i check the first five results of df$Group i get ``` "Group integer(0)" "Group c(Q40 = 2)" "Group c(Q3 = 1)"  "Group integer(0)" "Group c(Q41 = 3) ```

Comment: My update should fix this. This was due to the fact that you have one row without any '1'.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have 2 columns before `V` columns we can use `max.col` like

```
paste0("Group", max.col(replace(df, is.na(df), 0) == 1) - 2)
#[1] "Group1" "Group3" "Group2" "Group3" "Group1"
```

If there are variables in middle columns somwhere, we can subset those and use `max.col`

```
sub_df <- df[grep("^V", names(df))]
paste0("Group", max.col(replace(sub_df, is.na(sub_df), 0) == 1))
```

Comment: I have 150 variables total - V1,V2,V3 are somewhere in the middle

Comment: @IG114 Updated the answer so that it will work irrespective where those variables are.

Answer (score 0):

An other quick use of apply :

```r
v1 <- c(1:3, NA, NA , NA)
v2 <- c(NA, NA , NA, 1:3)
df0 <- tibble::tibble(v1, v2)
df0[["group"]] <- apply(df0, 1, function(x) names(x)[!is.na(x)])
df0
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      v1    v2 group
#>   <int> <int> <chr>
#> 1     1    NA v1   
#> 2     2    NA v1   
#> 3     3    NA v1   
#> 4    NA     1 v2   
#> 5    NA     2 v2   
#> 6    NA     3 v2
```